# Interrupt handler code executed concurrently with the user code

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, uart, interrupt-handling

I have written a simple UART driver using interrupt.Right now I am only transmitting the data.

write function in the user space copies the data to the buffer in kernel space.

Now during Interrupt the data in kernel space is copied byte wise(100 times) from kernel space to THR buffer register.

But before the Interrupt handler completes it job,the debug statements in close function gets printed.Isn't it the wrong way?ie I want the debug statements of close function to be printed after the statements of handler function

The code below is the handler function and this handler function is enabled just after the copyfromuser function

```
irqreturn_t uart_handler(int irq, void *dev_id) 
{
    write_to_uart(bytes_written);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "index %d\n", Uindex);

    if (Uindex >= 100)
        iowrite32(0,io_map + 0x4);//IER THR disable

    printk(KERN_ALERT "out from if\n");

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

The code below is the write_to_uart

```
void write_to_uart(int nofbytes)
{
    if (((ioread32(io_map + 0x8)) & 0x2) == 0x2) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Interrupt activated\n");
        iowrite32((unsigned)((device_buffer)[Uindex]), io_map);
        Uindex++;
    } else {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Interrupt not activated\n");
        printk(KERN_ALERT "IIR reg = %d\n", ioread32(io_map + 0x8));
    }
}
```

The close function does nothing

```
int uart_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "DEVICE CLOSED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Don't try to highlight your question using quote tags.  You haven't shown enough of your code.  Is this a non-blocking write on the app side?  What does your driver's `close()` function do?  Separating a pair of **spin_lock()** and **spin_unlock()** across two functions is poor coding practice.  It's not necessary and a waste of time to (re)enable the interrupt during servicing each interrupt.  Also you should learn the [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle).

Comment: @sawdust:Thanks for the document.It is non-blocking write in the app side.Close function does nothing.After the Interrupt handler complete its job I do not have any control over the code.

Comment: *"It is non-blocking write"*  -- Then that explains why the app can perform a **close()**, which then *"does nothing"*.  So the code is performing as it should, just not as you (incorrectly) expected.  If the app wants to delay until the data has been transmitted, then either use blocking **write()** or call **tcdrain()**.  Your driver's **close()** could also be better behaved by deferring its return until the fd's output is actually complete.

Comment: @sawdust:"Blocking write" did not help.I used wait_event() and wake_up() appropriately.It worked in the correct manner.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no code in the interrupt handler that would be able to block the `write(2)` call, the data will be sent to the UART asynchronously. Assuming that you proceed to `close(2)` the file descriptor after the data has been written (as perceived from user-space); the behavior that you are describing is exactly what I would expect to see.

If you wan't to make the write be blocking, have a look at [completions](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/completion.h).

On a side note; is there any reason why you can't use the standard 8250/16550 driver in the kernel?

Comment: :The code behaved in the right manner when I introduced wait_event(..)and wake_up(..) in the appropriate place.Nothing wrong in the 8250/16550 driver,just wanted to explore and learn.